# Android: Create new ImageView by every button click

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, buttonclick

I want to generate and add a new ImageView by a button click everytime the button is pressed. This is my code:

```
entwicklungskarte.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.erfindungek);
            ResourcenActivity.entwicklungskarten.add(iv);
        }
    });
```

But when I click on the button twice, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I thought that it would create a new ImageView by every button click. But it obviously doesn't. Is there any other way to create and add an ImageView to the layout by button click?

Comment: Why not using a list view, and with image view in the entries, and adding items to it

Comment: Please translate all code to English and provide the code inside `ResourcenActivity.entwicklungskarten.add(iv)`

Comment: `thought that it would create a new ImageView by every button click. But it obviously doesn't`. Well it does. Its on adding that you have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a field previousId in you class
private int previousId=0;
You will have to set an incremental id of your image view iv

```
 iv.setId(++previousId);
```

before

```
ResourcenActivity.entwicklungskarten.add(iv);
```

So that every time the corresponding parent is asked to add a new child with different ID than the previous one.

Comment: Thank you! This is working!
So before, every new ImageView-call was a new ImageView but with the same ID as the ones before, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(view != null) {
    return view; 
}
```

Comment: This question will marked as low quality. Please provide more information.